# How to query/check for specific key/value pair in FIrebase using Swift3

Tags: ios, firebase

In my app I want to check if a specific order already exists. I'm struggling on how to do this type of query.

How can I check if a particular order exists in the child("orders")?  For instance I want to query to see if order 2 exists

DB_name
--users
----UserID
------Orders
--------Order1
----------OrderItem1
----------OrderItem2
----------OrderItem3
--------Order2
----------OrderItem1
----------OrderItem2
----------OrderItem3
--------Order3
----------OrderItem1
----------OrderItem2
----------OrderItem3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need three things:

First, a reference to that child. There are a couple ways to get one, but I find the following format easy to read:

```
FIRDatabase.database()
    .reference()
    .child("users")
    .child("userID")
    .child("Orders")
    .child("Order2")
```

Second, the value of that child in the form of a `FIRDataSnapshot`. We get values by observing "events" of type `value`. Check out [`observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock:`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_query.html#a403e05f65d5a4d597392e232247f9d6a) for the simplest approach.

Third, evaluate the `FIRDataSnapshot` we get back from the observer to see what the value actually is. If you simply want to know whether it exists, the [`exists`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.html#af14cbacf7ef15cf8c31196bc03e9db09) method is quite useful.

Putting it all together, we get the following:

```
FIRDatabase.database()
    .reference()
    .child("users")
    .child("userID")
    .child("Orders")
    .child("Order2")
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print("Exists: \(snapshot.exists())")
    }
```

Comment: Works, just had to add () to snapshot.exists() to get back the true/false value instead of Function.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know why swift3 would be getting error: Ambiguous use of 'observe Single Event(of:with:)' when try to do anything besides the print() line?  For instance, if I try to add an if statement I get the Ambigous error.

Comment: That usually means there is more than one method that matches that function signature and it's having trouble figuring out which one you're trying to use. Give it a hint by changing `observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot)` to `observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot)`